# FoxPro Temp File Issue

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

We have the following line of Visual FoxPro 9 code

```
INDEX ON batchno TO temp FOR !DELETED()
```

We are having an issue where a FoxPro compiled application will run, try to enumerate the contents of a folder, look for a temp file, create the temp file (database called temp.idx), and then move on to further processing to reference the temporary data.

This seemed to work fine when we were on a Novell directory server with NFS file system.  However, now that we have moved to MS Active Directory server with NTFS file system, we are having an issue such that the compiled FoxPro application is not able to write to the file anymore.

Process Monitor shows the following output when the error occurs:

```
Operation:   CreateFile
Result:   SHARING VIOLATION
Desired Access:  Generic Read/Write
Disposition:  OverwriteIf
Options:  Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File
Attributes:  N
ShareMode:  None
AllocationSize:  0
```

I was curious if there was an alternate way to approach this situation where we do not have to worry about the application keeping the file in use (presumably read) while it attempts to write the file, where is subsequently fails since it is already in use.

Comment: How is the table created.... select * from into??? or create table ... or is it a table always there... can you post some segments of the code?

Answer (score 0):

A .IDX file is a standalone index file containing one index, as opposed to .CDX which is a compound index file that can contain many.

Is it a permissions issue - does it work when you run it as a network administrator?

What version of FoxPro / Visual FoxPro is the EXE compiled in ?

What are the client and server OS ?

Answer (score 0):

It's important which OS you are using! If the program runs on Windows Vista, 7 or Server 2008 you are not able to create files everywhere you want without restrictions.
The best way is to create this temporary index in the TEMP-Directory of the user. There you have always full rights do write or delete files.
If you just use

```
INDEX ON batchno TO temp FOR !DELETED()
```

the IDX will be created in the default directory. If this directory is C:\Program Files... the UAC of Windows will not allow to write it there and redirect the file into a temporary directory somewhere under c:\Windows.
With SYS(2023) you are able to get the TEMP-Directory of the user.
So try this:

```
INDEX ON batchno TO (SYS(2023) + "\temp.idx") FOR !DELETED()
```